# WM_SETTEXT & WM_GETTEXT delay/lag issue

Tags: vb.net, delay, wait, lag, sendmessage

I have tried automating a few external window's Combo box controls using the API functions, SendMessage and PostMessage and using the Window Messages WM_SETTEXT WM_GETTEXTLENGTH and WM_GETTEXT.

I can get this to work when I run through the code for example pressing F11 through each line or putting a breakpoint in and running it at a certain point, but when I run it as normal, the WM_SETTEXT message doesn't update the Combo box.

It seems to be an issue with the speed that the code is running so my first solution was to put a piece of validation that ensures the text is in the combo box, but for some reason the WM_GETTEXT retrieves the text that should be in the text box even though its not visible.

The code below is a snippet of the kind of validation I've tried, my question here would be is there any sort of wait until method I could use to ensure that the text actually gets entered, I know about the Sleep API but I would ideally like something that actually makes sure that text is there and doesn't load f x seconds and hopes that the text is there.

Any ideas are appriciated.

Many Thanks

VB.net Code Example:

```
Private Enum WindowMessages
    WM_SETTEXT = &HC
    WM_GETTEXT = &HD
    WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = &HE
End Enum

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias _
"SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Int32, ByVal wMsg As Int32, ByVal _
wParam As Int32, lParam As String) As Int32

Public Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal hWnd
As Int32, _
ByVal wMsg As Int32, ByVal wParam As Int32, ByVal lParam As String) As Int32

Private Sub TestExample(ByVal hWndTextBox as Int32, ByVal TextString as String)
'####Using the hWnd of a Combo box control and a string to enter in the combo box.####    

    Dim TextLength as Int32
    Dim ItemText as string

    Do until ItemText = TextString
        SendMessage(hWndTextBox, WM_SETTEXT, 0, TextString) > 0
        TextLength = SendMessage(hWndTextBox, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0)
        ItemText = Space(TextLength)
        SendMessage(hWndTextBox, WM_GETTEXT, TextLen + 1, ItemText)      
    Loop

End Sub
```